# Start JVM not working

Tags: java, python, eclipse, jvm, jpype

I have on my comp: python 2.7- 32bit , eclipse 64-bit and java 8 64-bit.
I have installed jpype -32bit for python 2.7 . Jpype is importing normally 
but i am facing a problem that is when i call:

```
jpype.getDefaultJVMPath() it is returning none.
```

also i can not run JVM:

```
jpype.isJVMStarted() is returning 0
```

and this is not working:

```
JVM = 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_91\\jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll'
jpype.startJVM(JVM , '-ea')
```

Please anyone tell me what the problem is and how to fix it? is it a 32 - 64 bit conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
1. Uninstall JDK and remove any environment variables of JAVA_Home.
2. Install Latest version of JDK and don't worry about environment variables because it automatically does.
3. Install Javabridge package in Python.

```
pip install javabridge
```

4.Javabridge might require numpy

```
pip install numpy
```

5.now try to import javabridge in python.

```
import javabridge
```

6. if successfully imported without any error of unable to start jvm or jvm.dll then your problem is solved.